# TypeError: unsupported operand type in Python

Tags: python, typeerror

'Homework' Question in Python Book: 
Write a program that prompts the user to enter 3 points of a triangle angle and display its area, using the equations given:

```
s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2
area = √s(s - side1)(s - side2)(s - side3)
```

The program I wrote when executed, displays an error, which I don't understand the root cause of and how to fix.

```js
   #Calculate the area of a triangle
   # Enter coordinates for 3 points
   sideOne = 1.5, -3.4#(x1, y1) = eval(input("Enter coords for side1:"))
   sideTwo = 4.6, 5#(x2, y2) = #eval(input("Enter coords for side2:"))
    sideThree = 9.5, -3.4#(x3, y3) = #eval(input("Enter coords for side3:"))

   # Calculate s value
    sideAll = (sideOne + sideTwo + sideThree) / 2# Compute Area
    area = (sideAll(sideAll - sideOne)(sideAll - sideTwo)(sideAll - sideThree)) * * 0.5# Display Area
    print("The Area of entered Triangle:", area)
```

Resulting Error

```js
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "J:\Programming\PROGRAMMING\Python\Exercises\Chapter 2\Programming Exercises - 2.14 Skip.py", line 8, in < module >
  sideAll = (sideOne + sideTwo + sideThree) / 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for / : 'tuple'
and 'int'
```

Comment: this might help you in understanding the error better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051233/python-mysql-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `sideOne = 1.5, -3.4`, then `sideOne` is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

So it is basically (as you say in your comments) fthe coordinates of one of your 3 points in the form of `(x,y)`, here `(1.5, -3.4)`.
You cannot do arithmetic operations directly on tuples, it has no sense to do this because tuples are just a way of representing data and python does not guess that it is a coordinate.
Instead you can do mathematical operations on numerical values (integer, float and so on) but not on tuples.

Instead, you might want to compute *the length* of your side and then use it as given in your formula.

You might want to try something like this :

```
import math

#Calculate the area of a triangle
# Enter coordinates for 3 points
a = 1.5, -3.4#(x1, y1) = eval(input("Enter coords for side1:"))
b = 4.6, 5#(x2, y2) = #eval(input("Enter coords for side2:"))
c = 9.5, -3.4#(x3, y3) = #eval(input("Enter coords for side3:"))

# Calculate the length of the sides from the 3 triangle points
sideOne = math.sqrt( (b[0]-a[0])**2 + (b[1]-a[1])**2 )
sideTwo = math.sqrt( (c[0]-b[0])**2 + (c[1]-b[1])**2 )
sideThree = math.sqrt( (a[0]-c[0])**2 + (a[1]-c[1])**2 )

# Calculate s value
sideAll = (sideOne + sideTwo + sideThree) / 2 # Compute Area
area = math.sqrt(sideAll * (sideAll - sideOne) * (sideAll - sideTwo) * (sideAll - sideThree)) # Display Area
print("The Area of entered Triangle:", area)
```

Note I prefer to use the `math.sqrt` function rather than non-integer power but this is just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

the `(side1 + side2 + side3)` result of is tuple.

e.g.

```
>>> sideOne = 1.5, -3.4
>>> sideTwo = 4.6, 5
>>> sideThree = 9.5, -3.4
>>> type(sideOne)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> sideOne + sideTwo + sideThree
(1.5, -3.4, 4.6, 5, 9.5, -3.4)
>>> a = sideOne + sideTwo + sideThree
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
>>>
```

Can not divide tuple by integer, it will raise `TypeError` exception.

e.g.

```
>>> (1,2)/2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

---

Use `Pythagoras theorem` to get length of each side.

code:

```
import math

# Three co-ordinates. 
sideOne = 1.5, -3.4
sideTwo = 4.6, 5
sideThree = 9.5, -3.4

# Find lenght of each side by Pythagoras theorem.
side1_x, side1_y = abs(sideOne[0] - sideTwo[0]), abs(sideOne[1] - sideTwo[1])
side2_x, side2_y = abs(sideTwo[0] - sideThree[0]), abs(sideTwo[1] - sideThree[1])
side3_x, side3_y = abs(sideThree[0] - sideOne[0]), abs(sideThree[1] - sideOne[1])

len_12 =  math.sqrt(side1_x*side1_x + side1_y*side1_y)
len_23 =  math.sqrt(side2_x*side2_x + side2_y*side2_y)
len_31 =  math.sqrt(side3_x*side3_x + side3_y*side3_y)
print "Length of sides:- ", len_12, len_23, len_31
```

Output:

```
Length of sides:-  8.95377015564 9.72471079261 8.0
```